# Nativescript record audio

Tags: audio, record, nativescript

I am searching for a solution to record audio and save the file on the device. I am building my app with Nativescript for IOS and Android, but i can not seem to find any documentation about recording audio only. Does Nativescript have this? Or would it be wise to build native apps for IOS and Android?

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify your device and give a more-specific description of what you are trying to do?  This questions is overly broad as it is.

Comment: I'm building Hybrid, so practically all devices.

Comment: As you're building this in NativeScript you _are_ building a Native app! Take a look at this 3 minute video to understand the architecture of NativeScript https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3_ZnWTj-NA. This also means that you have full access to the iOS/Android API:s. NativeScript does not have a multiplatform way of recording audio (yet). What you want to do is calls to the Android/iOS API:s directly. See e.g. http://developer.telerik.com/featured/nativescript-works/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin was recently finished to include iOS support: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-audio

If you have any issues the repo is here: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio

You can record audio and play back audio files via URL or locally.